# Can't delete old messages in message queue C

Tags: c, key, message-queue

I have created a msq to let two processes communicate to one another. The problem is that I'm having some issues since after a couple of time that I run my code some of the old messages of the previous executions show up. This bothers me because I need to perform controls on the current data and cant do it because of this. I tried irpcm -q msqid but it does not do anything except shutting down my program the next time I run it. I even tried hardcoding some keys thinking that it would help but nothing. Also tried to msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, 0) after I finished using the queue but nothing. Hope you can help me out and thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

*sender.c*

```
#define MAXSIZE     1024


struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};


void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int msqid1;
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
key_t keymq1;
struct msgbuf sbuf;
size_t buflen;
keymq1 = 668;
sbuf.mtype = 1;
if ((msqid1 = msgget(keymq1, msgflg )) < 0)
    die("msgget");
sbuf.mtype = 1;

  strcpy(sbuf.mtext,"my message");
    buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;
    if (msgsnd(msqid1, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
    {
        printf ("%d, %ld, %s, %zu\n", msqid1, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buflen);
        die("msgsnd");
    }

    else {
        printf("Message sent\n");
 }
```

*receiver.c*

```
#define MAXSIZE     1024


struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};


void die(char *s)
{
    perror(s);
    exit(1);
}

int msqid;
key_t keymq1;
struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;
keymq1 = 668;
if ((msqid = msgget(keymq1, 0666)) < 0)
    die("msgget()");

    if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0)
        die("msgrcv");

    printf("Message received: %s\n", rcvbuffer.mtext);
```

Comment: first should be in `root(su)` mode. which message `queue id` you are unable to delete ?

Comment: the queue id is 65536, I have already tried to delete it through ipcrm but it still gives me problems

Comment: use `ipcrm -q 65536` otherwise delete using `key` ?

Answer (score 0):

To delete `message queue` with message `queue Id` use

```
ipcrm -q id
```

or delete the `message queue` using `key` value as

```
ipcrm -Q key_num
```

From man page "*In order to delete such objects, you must be superuser, or the cre‐
       ator or owner of the object.*"

Finally you can delete the message queue using `IPC_RMID` flag in `msgctl()` call as

```
main()
{
        int total_mq,i,msqid;
        struct msqid_ds ds; //dataStructure holding complete info for indexed message que
        struct msginfo msginfo; //general buff copying data from MSG_INFO, has info of how many message que present right now
        /* Obtain size of kernel 'entries' array */
        total_mq = msgctl(0, MSG_INFO, (struct msqid_ds *) &msginfo); //copy kernel MSGQ_INFO to local buff
        //returns count of active message Q
        if (total_mq < 0)
        {
                perror("msgctl");
                return 0;
        }
        printf("no of active message queue(KEY) : %d\n", total_mq+1);
        /* Retrieve meaasge Queue id's */
        for (i = 0; i <= total_mq; i++)
        {
                msqid = msgctl(i, MSG_STAT, &ds); //from each index using MSG_STAT -> ds, return msgqid
                if (msqid <0 )
                {
                        perror("msgctl");
                        return 0;
                }
                /* using msgqid remove the message queue */
                if ( msgctl(msqid,IPC_RMID,0) < 0 )
                {
                        perror("msgctl");
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        printf("all message queues removed\n");
        return 0;
}
```

before running above code, create some message queues and then delete those.